# Special Character in Property setting in artifactory through jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am following [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-SettingandDeletingPropertiesonFilesinArtifactory.1) link to add properties to a file in artifactory. But I am not able to find a way to add special characters in values of Property. Is there any escape character to do this.

I have tried using `\` and `%5C` as suggested for api in artifactory. But it is not working for pipeline.

This is my pipeline script

```
node('master'){
stage('test'){
    def arti_server = Artifactory.server 'Artifactory_Server'
    def setPropsSpec = """{
                        "files": [{
                                "pattern": "test/test.groovy"
                                    }
                                ]
                        }"""


arti_server.setProps spec: setPropsSpec, props: "p1=%5C;1;p2=test2"
}
}
```

Error I am getting is because it is not taking `;` as escape character. Instead it is taking it as another property. Here is my ERROR

```
java.io.IOException: Setting properties: Every property must have at least one value.
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.EditPropertiesHelper.validateSetProperties(EditPropertiesHelper.java:93)
```

Comment: Please share with us your pipeline, and the error you receive.

Comment: I have made the required changes